# How to add firebase recapcha multiple time on same page?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, recaptcha

on my page having two form and need to implement firebase recaptcha verifier on both form.how to add firebase authenication on both form?
The Recaptcha doesn't even render, and the window.repcaptchaVerfier.render() does not render

```
<form id="form1">
<div id="recaptcha"></div>
</form>   
<form id="form2">

<div id="recaptcha2"></div>
</form> 

 window.recaptcha = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha1', {
          'size': 'normal',
          'callback': function(response) {
            console.log("callback");
            // reCAPTCHA solved, allow signInWithPhoneNumber.
            // [START_EXCLUDE]
            // updateSignInButtonUI();
            // [END_EXCLUDE]
          },
          'expired-callback': function() {
            console.log("expired-callback");
            // Response expired. Ask user to solve reCAPTCHA again.
            // [START_EXCLUDE]
            // updateSignInButtonUI();

            // [END_EXCLUDE]
          }
        });

window.recaptcha.render().then(function(widgetId) { 

  window.recaptchaId = widgetId;

});
    window.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha2', {
          'size': 'normal',
          'callback': function(response) {
            console.log("callback");
            // reCAPTCHA solved, allow signInWithPhoneNumber.
            // [START_EXCLUDE]
            // updateSignInButtonUI();
            // [END_EXCLUDE]
          },
          'expired-callback': function() {
            console.log("expired-callback");
            // Response expired. Ask user to solve reCAPTCHA again.
            // [START_EXCLUDE]
            // updateSignInButtonUI();

            // [END_EXCLUDE]
          }
        });
window.recaptchaVerifier.render().then(function(widgetId) { 

      window.recaptchaWidgetId = widgetId;

    });
```

Comment: It should render. What error are you seeing? Make sure you initialize the Auth instance before you render the reCAPTCHA.

Comment: did you get the answer for this?